# How to get more filtered search ressults

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to search for a particular string using the following command.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id), * 
FROM SYSCOMMENTS 
WHERE   
text like '%prof%'
```

I am getting all the search results with **Prof** as an item - 5292 rows.

But, here the problem is that I am getting all the search results like below WHERE I DON'T WANT BELOW RESULTS, for example:

- UserLogin**Prof**ile
- UserLogin**Prof**ileExceptions etc.

I want the results in such a way that I want only **Prof**.
Can anybody suggest me how can I modify the above query!

Searching for my required string **Prof** from among 5292 search results is very difficult within the available time

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `I want the results in such a way that I want only Prof.` - this line does not make sense. Do you want only 'Prof' in result set?

Answer (score 1):

You should try,

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id), * 
FROM SYSCOMMENTS 
WHERE   
text like '% prof %'
```